# Getting NameResolutionError: Failed to resolve 'oauth2.googleapis.com' trying to upload file to Google Cloud Storage via app on local k8s cluster

Tags: python, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-storage

I have Kubernetes deployment with the following config

```
resource "kubernetes_deployment" "batch-producer" {
  metadata {
    name = var.app-name
    namespace = var.k8s-namespace.metadata[0].name
    labels = {
      app = var.app-name
    }
  }

  spec {
    replicas = 1

    selector {
      match_labels = {
        app = var.app-name
      }
    }

    template {
      metadata {
        labels = {
          app = var.app-name
        }
      }

      spec {
        container {
          name  = var.app-name
          image = var.docker-image

          image_pull_policy = "Never"

          port { container_port = 80 }
          port { container_port = 443 }

          command = [
            "sh",
            "-exc",
            <<-EOT
            mkdir /secrets
            echo ${var.storage-sa-key} | base64 --decode > ./secrets/gcp_creds.json
            python ./run.py
            
            EOT
            ,
            ""
          ]

          env_from {
            config_map_ref {
              name = "batch-producer-config"
            }
          }

          env {
            name = "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"
            value = "/secrets/gcp_creds.json"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And app should just write file to GCS

```
class GCSWriter(AbstractWriter):
    def __init__(self, properties: dict):
        self.storage_client = storage.Client() \
            .from_service_account_json(json_credentials_path=os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"])
        self.bucket_name = properties.get("bucket_name")
        self.logger = get_logger()

    def write(self, source_path):
        # time.sleep(100)
        bucket = self.storage_client.bucket(self.bucket_name)
        blob = bucket.blob(os.path.join(
            "incomes_data_source",
            dt.today().strftime('%Y/%m/%d'),
            os.path.split(source_path)[1]))
        blob.upload_from_filename(source_path)
        self.logger.info("File '%s' was uploaded to GCS successfully", source_path)
```

App deploys, but I'm getting the following error after some time:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /token (Caused by NameResolutionError("<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f993b606bd0>: Failed to resolve 'oauth2.googleapis.com' ([Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution)"))
```

I tried to ping google.com or download random file via curl from pod - success.
I also tried to use existing access-key.json running same container just via docker - it also works and I can see uploaded file in GCS.
Looking for a clue how I can resolve this.

Comment: Did you check CoreDNS logs?

Comment: Thanks for an idea. There is an error "plugin/errors: 2 oauth2.googleapis.com. A: dns: overflow unpacking uint32". Version: CoreDNS-1.11.1. I'll try to google it

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Vasilii Angapov comment I found this issue - https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/7110.

I didn't dive deep into root cause, I just followed recommendation for downgrading to CoreDNS-1.10.0.

```
kubectl edit deployment/coredns -n kube-system
```

Changed version from 1.11.1 to 1.10.0 and wait for deployment to restart.

Everything works after that in my setup (Docker Desktop v4.27.1, Kubernetes v1.29.1)

I also tried to launch same configuration via Rancher Desktop with Kubernetes v1.28.n, it also works well.